# AutoHotKey: wait for process, breaking on user input

Tags: process, user-input, autohotkey

A script is waiting for a process to start; it shall do so indefinitely, but only as long as there is no human input. In another words: the script shall wait for either process start or human input, whichever comes first (also, the process may already be running when the script starts, in which case the script shall close immediately). I have thought of something like this, but there’s likely a better way, since this loop doesn’t break with input:

```
while (A_TimeIdlePhysical > 100) {
    Process, Wait, SomeProcess.exe
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with notepad:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, DetectProcess, 50
return

DetectProcess:
If (ProcessExist("notepad.exe")) ; if the process is already running
    ExitApp
; otherwise:
If (A_TimeIdlePhysical > 100) ; as long as there is no human input
{
    If (ProcessExist("notepad.exe"))  ; wait for either process start
        ExitApp
}
else ;  or human input
    ExitApp
return

ProcessExist(ProcessName){
Process, Exist, %ProcessName%
return Errorlevel
}
```